# Why level curves of $z^2$ are not orthogonal for $u=v=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, examples-counterexamples, curves

**Theorem.** Let the function $f(z) = u(x, y) + iv(x, y)$ be analytic in a domain $D$, and Let the families of level curves be $u(x, y) = c_1$ and $v(x, y) = c_2$, where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are arbitrary real constants. Then these families are orthogonal.

Regarding the mentioned Theorem the two following examples are confusing:

Consider $f(z)=z^2$. I plot the $x^2-y^2=a$ and $2xy=b$ for different values of a and b and they are orthogonal and I tried for a=b=0 but it **fails** to be orthogonal! Does it contradict with the above theorem?

And, consider $f(z)=\dfrac{1}{z}$. I plot the $x/(x^2+y^2)=a$ and $y/(x^2+y^2)=b$ for different values of a and b and they are orthogonal and I tried for a=b=0 and still it **doesn't** fail to be orthogonal but $f(z)=\dfrac{1}{z}$ is not analytic for $z=0$! Does it contradict with the above theorem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The theorem is only valid for those points at which $f'$ is not $0$. The explains your first question.

Concerning the second one, the function isn't even *defined* at $0$.

Comment: So if $f'$ is zero then $u_x=v_x=0$ and thus $u_y=v_y=0$ so a condition Dini's Theorem fails to satisfy, am I right?

Comment: @Edi In order for me to answer that question, you'll have to tell me which theoreom is that. It can't be [the one I know](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DinisTheorem.html).

Comment: No this is another theorem of same person!.. Anyway, I found out what I needed. Thanks so much :)

Comment: @Edi I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

The curves $x^2-y^2=a$ and $xy=b$ are two pencils of equilateral hyperbolas (actually the same pencils, rotated by $45°$).

You can observe that all these curves are orthogonal to each other, with a single exception: $a=b=0$. But the world is safe because at the intersection point $(z=0$), the curves don't have a unique direction and the property has no meaning there.